# Perkin's age problem

Tags: mathematics

Perkin and Poise's combined age is 22 which is 3 years more than the combined age of Perkin and Pootle which is 2 years more than Poise's and Pootle's age combined.

The question is -

In how many years will the sum of all their ages be 56?

Comment: I'm not seeing a reason for these close votes.  It might not be a particularly inspired puzzle, but it is a puzzle.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its-

> 9 years

Explanation -

> Perkin $+$ Poise $= 22$
>  Perkin $+$ Pootle $= 19$ [$22-3$]
>  Poise $+$ Pootle $= 17$ [$19-2$]
>  Solving them we get,
>  Perkin = 12, Poise = 10, Pootle = 7, sum= 29, required sum 56,
>  difference = 27, sum will increase by 3 each year so required time = 9 years

Answer (score 5):

> 9 years
>
>  a=Perkin
>  b=Poise
>  c=Pootle
>
>  a+b=22
>  a+c=19
>  b+c=17
>
>  2(a+b+c)=58
>
>  a+b+c=29
>
>  29 + 3*years=56
>
>  years = 9

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> 9 years

My reasoning is:

> Twice the current combined age of Perkin, Poise and Pootle is $3\times22-3-(3+2)=66-3-5=58$. Their combined age twice will be $2\times56=112$, in $112-58=54$ years. There are $3$ of them, we are counting each person twice, hence the event will occur in $\frac{54}{2\times3}=9$ years time.